# MVC Core 5 Redirect user to View in Area after login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a login page which is outside Area and after successful login I want to redirect the user to a View inside Area.

I tried below code but it didn't work.

```
return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home", new { Area = "StaffAug"});  
return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "StaffAug/Home");
```

it's redirecting to Home/Dashboard?area=StaffAug instead of StaffAug/Home/Dashboard

```
[Area("StaffAug")] 
public class HomeController : Controller 
{ 
 private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger; 
 public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger) { _logger = logger; } 
 public IActionResult Dashboard() { return View(); } 
}
```

Comment: You need to verify your Action Names are correct. You should use `nameof()` to ensure they're always correct.

Comment: Action names are correct.

Comment: Action names cannot contain slashes, so your posted code with `"StaffAug/Home"` _cannot_ be "correct".

Comment: I tried using Area/Controller which didn't work

Comment: Dashboard is action name not controller.

Comment: Please post the definition of your `HomeController` class.

Comment: [Area("StaffAug")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Dashboard()
        {
            return View();
        }                                                                                                                                                   }

Comment: Please edit your original post instead of posting unformatted code in comments.

Comment: The problem is that your `Dashboard()` action method has no parameters, so none of those `RedirectToAction` methods correctly match it.

Comment: How can i redirect to StaffAug/Home/Dashboard ?

Comment: Hi @Mohan Raju, Please check my answer below. 
If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure add area route to Startup.cs:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "MyArea",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Then use `return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home", new { Area = "StaffAug" });`

Reference:

[Areas in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0)